# Qt widgets overlapping in layout

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have the following code in the contructor of my main window, which extends `QMainWindow` class:

```
QHBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);

QPushButton* button0 = new QPushButton(this);
button0->setText("Button 0");
mainLayout->addWidget(button0);

QPushButton* button1 = new QPushButton(this);
button1->setText("Button 1");
button1->setMinimumWidth(500);
mainLayout->addWidget(button1);

QPushButton* button2 = new QPushButton(this);
button2->setText("Button 2");
mainLayout->addWidget(button2);

setMinimumSize(700,480);
this->setLayout(mainLayout);
```

However, when I tried to run this, the buttons seem to be overlapping on the top left corner. What should I change here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the console output. Usually main windows do have layout by default, then you just need to set it on the central widget instead of the window itself:

```
this->centralWidget()->setLayout(mainLayout);
```

If central widget does not exist (for example you deleted auto-generated .ui file) then just create it manually:

```
QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
QHBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout(centralWidget);

QPushButton* button0 = new QPushButton(this);
button0->setText("Button 0");
mainLayout->addWidget(button0);

QPushButton* button1 = new QPushButton(this);
button1->setText("Button 1");
button1->setMinimumWidth(500);
mainLayout->addWidget(button1);

QPushButton* button2 = new QPushButton(this);
button2->setText("Button 2");
mainLayout->addWidget(button2);

setMinimumSize(700,480);
```

Comment: The console says `QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MainWindow "", which already has a layout`, and `button2` seems to be filling the whole window. Replacing `this` with `this->centralWidget()` results in a seg fault.

Comment: @Henry W. That message is apperently the reason. Do you have some auto-generated line like `ui->setupUi(this);` before you code? If yes then try `ui->centralWidget->...`, if no then just add your layout into exisiting one

Comment: No. I deleted the auto generated ui file. What do you mean by adding the layout into the existing one?